# Table ListObject not limited to rows of table but counts the whole sheet

Tags: vba, excel, with-statement

I created two named tables in excel using the insert / table commands and naming them as below.  In excel all looks fine.  The row count of table House_details is 50 including the header row and that of Sale_price_schedule 15 including the header row.

My relevant vba code is

```
        Set tblHouseDetails = Sheets("House details").ListObjects("House_details")
        Set tblSalePriceSchedule = Sheets("Sale price schedule").ListObjects("Sale_price_schedule")
        'Find the product type, look for the relevant price and insert it into the appropriate house details column
        With tblHouseDetails.DataBodyRange
            For iCount = 2 To Rows.Count
                iTemp = Rows.Count
                strProductType = Cells(iCount, 5).Value 'The fifth columns is the product type
                dSaleDate = Cells(iCount, 3).Value 'The third column is the sale date
                'Find the correct sale price in the SalePriceSchedule
                '----------------------------
                dblSalePrice = -999
                With tblSalePriceSchedule.DataBodyRange
                    iTemp = Rows.Count
                    For iCount2 = 2 To Rows.Count
                        If Cells(iCount2, 3) = strProductType And Cells(iCount2, 1) <= dSaleDate And Cells(iCount2, 2) >= dSaleDate Then
                            dblSalePrice = Cells(iCount2, 4)
                        End If


                    Next iCount2
                End With
                '------------------------------
                Cells(iCount, 6) = dblSalePrice
            Next iCount
        End With
```

My problem is that the tblHouseDetails row count is not the 50 rows I have defined in Excel, but the full sheet (1048576).

Why is my Rows.Count incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When "Rows" and "Cells" are used alone, they refer to "ActiveSheet.Rows" and "ActiveSheet.Cells".

If you wish to refer to the range from "With.DataBodyRange", you need to add a dot in front (".Rows", ".Cells"):

```
Set tblHouseDetails = Sheets("House details").ListObjects("House_details")
Set tblSalePriceSchedule = Sheets("Sale price schedule").ListObjects("Sale_price_schedule")
'Find the product type, look for the relevant price and insert it into the appropriate house details column
With tblHouseDetails.DataBodyRange
    For iCount = 1 To .Rows.Count
        iTemp = .Rows.Count
        strProductType = .Cells(iCount, 5).Value 'The fifth columns is the product type
        dSaleDate = .Cells(iCount, 3).Value 'The third column is the sale date
        'Find the correct sale price in the SalePriceSchedule
        '----------------------------
        dblSalePrice = -999
        With tblSalePriceSchedule.DataBodyRange
            iTemp = .Rows.Count
            For iCount2 = 1 To .Rows.Count
                If .Cells(iCount2, 3) = strProductType And .Cells(iCount2, 1) <= dSaleDate And .Cells(iCount2, 2) >= dSaleDate Then
                    dblSalePrice = .Cells(iCount2, 4)
                End If
            Next iCount2
        End With
        '------------------------------
        .Cells(iCount, 6) = dblSalePrice
    Next iCount
End With
```

But a better solution would be to use the rows as a variable:

```
Dim rowsA As Range, rowsB As Range
Set rowsA = tblHouseDetails.DataBodyRange.Rows
Set rowsB = tblSalePriceSchedule.DataBodyRange.Rows

'Find the product type, look for the relevant price and insert it into the appropriate house details column
For i = 1 To rowsA.Count
  strProductType = rowsA.Cells(i, 5).Value 'The fifth columns is the product type
  dSaleDate = rowsA.Cells(i, 3).Value 'The third column is the sale date

  'Find the correct sale price in the SalePriceSchedule
  dblSalePrice = -999
  For j = 1 To rowsB.Count
    If rowsB.Cells(j, 3) = strProductType And rowsB.Cells(j, 1) <= dSaleDate And rowsB.Cells(j, 2) >= dSaleDate Then
        rowsA.Cells(i, 6) = rowsB.Cells(j, 4)
    End If
  Next
Next
```

And if what you are looking for is a performant solution, I would work with the values in an array:

```
Dim dataA(), dataB(), i&, j&, strProductType$, dSaleDate, dblSalePrice

' Get all the values in an array
dataA = Sheets("House details").ListObjects("House_details").DataBodyRange.Value
dataB = Sheets("Sale price schedule").ListObjects("Sale_price_schedule").DataBodyRange.Value
For i = 0 To UBound(dataA)
  strProductType = dataA(i, 4) 'The fifth columns is the product type
  dSaleDate = dataA(i, 2) 'The third column is the sale date

  'Find the correct sale price in the SalePriceSchedule
  dblSalePrice = -999
  For j = 0 To UBound(dataB)
    If dataB(j, 2) = strProductType And dataB(j, 0) <= dSaleDate And dataB(j, 1) >= dSaleDate Then
        dataA(i, 5) = dataB(j, 3)
    End If
  Next
Next

' Copy the values back to the sheet
Sheets("House details").ListObjects("House_details").DataBodyRange.Value = dataA
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and the further education.  Makes it so much simpler. Unfortunately I cannot vote your answer up yet.

Comment: @Jean - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) You can always 'accept an answer' by clicking the gray checkmark.

Comment: @Jeeped, I know I can do this but I don't have the privilege yet.  I need 15 experience to be able to do so. Currently only on 11...

Comment: @Jean - you need 15 to upvote, anyone can accept an answer to their question .

Answer (score 0):

You are working within the [.DataBodyRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.databodyrange.aspx) of the House_details ListObject. All references used inside that [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) need to be prefaced with a period (aka *full stop* or `.`) in order to pass along the parent reference.

The `Rows.Count` needs to be `.Rows.Count`, the `Cells(iCount2, 3)` needs to be `.Cells(iCount2, 3)`, etc.

The [Range.Parent property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224980(v=office.11).aspx) shifts to the Sale_price_schedule table once you enter the nested With ... End With and these [Range.Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) and [Range.Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195745.aspx) properties require the same syntax to have their parent reference adjusted to the Sale_price_schedule table.

All of the `Cells(...)` and `Rows.Count` calls are defaulting to the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx) without the prefacing periods.

```
    Set tblHouseDetails = Sheets("House details").ListObjects("House_details")
    Set tblSalePriceSchedule = Sheets("Sale price schedule").ListObjects("Sale_price_schedule")
    'Find the product type, look for the relevant price and insert it into the appropriate house details column
    With tblHouseDetails.DataBodyRange
        For iCount = 2 To .Rows.Count
            iTemp = .Rows.Count
            strProductType = .Cells(iCount, 5).Value 'The fifth columns is the product type
            dSaleDate = .Cells(iCount, 3).Value 'The third column is the sale date
            'Find the correct sale price in the SalePriceSchedule
            '----------------------------
            dblSalePrice = -999
            With tblSalePriceSchedule.DataBodyRange
                iTemp = .Rows.Count
                For iCount2 = 2 To .Rows.Count
                    If .Cells(iCount2, 3) = strProductType And .Cells(iCount2, 1) <= dSaleDate And .Cells(iCount2, 2) >= dSaleDate Then
                        dblSalePrice = .Cells(iCount2, 4)
                    End If


                Next iCount2
            End With
            '------------------------------
            .Cells(iCount, 6) = dblSalePrice
        Next iCount
    End With
```

On a related note, retrieving the [Range.Row](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196952.aspx) property will retrieve the actual row on the worksheet and must be adjusted by the row of the [.HeaderRowRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.headerrowrange.aspx) to return the row position within the table.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.  It was exactly what was needed!